# Saving additional data about player. Android

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am going to build a real time multiplayer game for android. I'm planning to use Google Play Games Service https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer

I understand, that I can use Leaderboard to save main player stat, for example Wins. But I need to be able to implement a way to store more information about the player. For example wins, losses, inventory and etc. So when two players join game room, before the start they could see each other's information.

I wonder where this information should be saved so that when two players connect to the same game room, they can see each others data. If it is saved on client's device, I guess it is a risk that a cheater can upgrade his own stats somehow, am I right?

What is the best practice? Thank you.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Its not code related issue, I haven't started doing anything, I just have no idea how to do what I want to do. I mean what is the best practice.